# How to define multiple columns with specific width and centered?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, columns, width

I want to define multiple columns (using `*{}{}`), with specific width (using `m{}`), and centered (using `>{\centering}`). However, I am not able to combine the three of them. The MWE below can only center the first column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc|>{\centering}*{6}{m{0.8cm}}}
        \hline
        i & t & k & $D_{im1}$ & $D_{im2}$ & $D_{im3}$ & $D_{ir1}$ & $D_{ir2}$ & $D_{ir3}$ \\ 
        \hline
        1 & 1 & $m$ & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        1 & 2 & $m$ & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        1 & 3 & $r$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 \\ 
        2 & 1 & $r$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        2 & 2 & $r$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 \\ 
        2 & 3 & $m$ & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}   
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I use `*{6}{>{\centering}m{0.8cm}}` (as I originally attempted), it does not compile.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{ccc|*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.8cm}}}`, but I strongly suggest to define a column type for this!

Comment: Your definition of  with `\centering` will work for the first `m` column only, after that it is gone due to grouping. The `centering` must appear inside column repetition statement, i.e.  `*{6}{>{centering...}}`

Comment: I did look up for similar questions. There was no way I was going to find that one, with such a horrible title.

Comment: Never mind, finding sometimes similar questions is difficult

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use the `\newcolumntype` feature and define a new columntype, say `M`, for this.

The direct usage of `>{...}...` is possible as well but sometimes error-prone, especially if many of those specialized column types appear.

```
\begin{tabular}{*{6}M{0.8cm}}
```

however is much easier (after definition of `M`, of course)

The decimal values should be set with `S` columntypes from `siunitx`, however, that's another question and is not addressed here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc|*{6}{M{0.8cm}}}
%    \begin{tabular}{ccc|*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.8cm}}} % Alternative...
        \hline
        i & t & k & $D_{im1}$ & $D_{im2}$ & $D_{im3}$ & $D_{ir1}$ & $D_{ir2}$ & $D_{ir3}$ \\ 
        \hline
        1 & 1 & $m$ & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        1 & 2 & $m$ & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        1 & 3 & $r$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 \\ 
        2 & 1 & $r$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        2 & 2 & $r$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 \\ 
        2 & 3 & $m$ & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}   
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]